# Sed occasionally missing a capture group

Tags: sed, capture-group

I'm writing a script that will allow users to apply their own list of ACLs more simply as part of a broader directory creation script. Users will input either `u`/`user` or `g`/`group`, their name, and the basic options they want from `RWX`. I'm using sed to transform the input to a proper NFSv4 ACL:

```
sed -E 's/^/A:/;s/(u|user|roup):([A-Za-z0-9]*):(.*)/:\2@company.com:\3/'
```

When I input a list as follows to test: `u:user1:RWX,g:group1:RX`, I do see correct output of the user: `A::user1@company.com:RWX`, but the group does not apply properly: `A:g:group1:RX` instead of `A:g:group1@company.com:RX`. When I use `group:group1::RX` it properly returns `A:g:group1@company.com:RX`. I'm guessing it's because the `g` is not recognized as the first capture group, but I can't think how to correct that. Any tips?

Comment: There is no 'g' in your first capture group... only "roup". Typo?

Comment: @Friedrich Intended, because the output ACL in a group case should contain the `g`, but in a user case should be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use optional capture groups that you don't use in the replacement part to remove parts of the input and nested capture groups to remember just parts of the matched substrings:

```bash
printf '%s\n' 'u:user1:RWX' 'g:group1:RX' 'group:group1:RX' \
| sed -E 's/^/A:/;s/(u|(g)(roup)?):([A-Za-z0-9]*):(.*)/\2:\4@company.com:\5/'
```

Output:

```
A::user1@company.com:RWX
A:g:group1@company.com:RX
A:g:group1@company.com:RX
```

Comment: Re: the list, I'm looping through it already via something to the effect of `for item in $(echo $acl_list | tr , " ")`. I'm trying to maintain the `g` because it's supposed to go into the ACL as a group, which should be structured as `A:g:group1@company.com:RX`. The user `u` should not be in the ACL, as indicated in the [docs](https://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs4_acl).

Comment: @Yehuda: Check the update. If it's still not what you want, please provide a clear set of inputs and corresponding expected outputs.

Comment: I provided the expected outputs in the question.

Comment: So `user:user1::RWX` is not a possible input?

Comment: I've put in regex checks earlier in the script to prevent that. Please just answer the question as-is.

Comment: Thanks - it still provides the user `u` though, which is not indicated in the [docs](https://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs4_acl) and may break.

Comment: OK, found a sed solution that should work for your case.

Comment: That's brilliant, I knew I was just missing something capturing in there properly. Nested captures is brilliant. Thanks for sticking with that!